# No module named 'sklearn_genetic'

Tags: scikit-learn, genetic-algorithm

I installed sklearn-genetic as below.

```
pip install sklearn-genetic

conda install -c conda-forge sklearn-genetic
```

However, I get always error as below.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You sure working on the same *environment* where you installed the package? And why installing using both pip and conda?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same message. But this worked for me:

```
pip install sklearn-genetic-opt
```

check here https://sklearn-genetic-opt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/